# TestNG: How to get the current executed group

Tags: testng

Is there a way to get the name of the group that is being currently executed?

I tried:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(ITestContext context) {
    groups = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getIncludedGroups();
}
```

but this gives me all the groups that the current running method supports, not the current one being executed.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible.  If I were to execute tests based on the class they are in, or just execute a single method, what would that function return?

Comment: null because it's not applicable?  When you are executing groups there has to be state kept somewhere on what group is currently being executed, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the first group name to which executing `@Test` method belongs to:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method){
        Test testClass = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        System.out.println(testClass.groups()[0]);
    }
```

If you want to know the all groups name to which executing `@Test` method belongs to:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method){
        Test testClass = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < testClass.groups().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(testClass.groups()[i]);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This question is three years old.  Not applicable any more.  In any case you didn't answer the original question.  I wanted to know which group was currently being executed, not all the groups or the first group.

Comment: @kfox I see you said Not applicable any more, but did you find a solution? I would also like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Answering now as this question was tagged in a similar question but with a different use-case. So this might be helpful to anyone searching for an answer:

This is kind of a workaround:
Instead of getting `getIncludedGroups`, use `getName` and do the following:

```java
@BeforeMethod(groups = {"one", "two"} )
public void beforeMethod(ITestContext ctx) {
    String name = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getName();
    if(name.contains("GRP")) {
        String grpName = name.split("GRP-")[1];
        if(grpName.equals("one")) {
            // ......
        } else {
            // .....
        }
    }
}
```