# How to get current executed group (at running time)

Tags: java, testng

This has been asked years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471314/testng-how-to-get-the-current-executed-group), but unfortunately the question has no answer.

Is it possible to find out which group is currently being executed from within a test method in `TestNG`?

```java
@Test(groups = {"groupA", "groupB"} )
public void test1() {
    // if running groupA do X
    // if running groupB do Y
}
```

The corresponding suite file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite-testGroups" parallel="false" allow-return-values="true">
    <test name="testA">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="groupA" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="TestGroups" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="testB">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="groupB" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="dev.TestGroups" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a small workaround or in a more proper way. First I would mention the workaround (This might not woek if the test is run using xml).

1. Workaround - Get `ITestContext` in the test method and get the group name as below:

```java
@Test(groups = {"groupA", "groupB"} )
public void test1(ITestContext ctx) {
    String name = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getName();
    if(name.contains("GRP")) {
        String grpName = name.split("GRP-")[1];
        if(grpName.equals("groupA")) {
            // ......
        } else {
            // .....
        }
    }
}
```

2. More proper way.
   Define a class level attribute and use a before method to identify the group.

```java
public class MyTest {
    private boolean isGroupOne = false;

    @BeforeMethod(groups = {"groupA"})
    public void beforeMethod() {
        isGroupOne = true;
    }

    @Test(groups = {"groupA", "groupB"})
    public void myTest() {
        if(isGroupOne) {
            // Do X
            isGroupOne = false; // reset
        }else{
            // Do Y.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @airos you might need null checks for `name` , etc. I am not adding such things to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GauthamM but `ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getName()` seems to retrieve the name of the test, not the name of the running group.

Comment: @airos the above code works when you are running it as a group. I haven't checked with xml

Comment: @airos I have updated the answer to include a much more proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean notMyGroup = true;

@BeforeMethod(groups = {MY_GROUP})
public void beforeMethod() {
    notMyGroup = false;
}
```

You can take this example and add for each group to set group name variable